# Checking if current page is an attachment page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, url, hook

I'm not to sure if this is something that is handled by WordPress at all, but I'm looking for a way to check if the user is on an attachment's page. In other words, if the URL is a direct link to an image. Like:

http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/myimg.jpg

Are there any hooks on these pages? `wp_footer` doesn't work.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_attachment/

Comment: However, if the user is on a direct link to an image, there's no wordpress or PHP involved at all. The web server will simply return the image and nothing else.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for the quick response. So i take it there's no way to prevent people from getting there then? We just disabled right click on the website, but people savvy enough can just use developer tools to access images

Comment: If they can see the image on the page, they have already downloaded it. What problem are you trying to solve? Also, an attachment and an attachment page are two different things. An attachment page is just a type of page, containing an attachment while the attachment itself is the actual file, like an image.

Comment: You can read more about the differences [here](https://mageewp.com/making-good-use-of-wordpress-attachment-pages.html)

Comment: True, and I'm just brainstorming different ways of preventing the user from copying/ saving copyrighted images. Though it's pretty much impossible, making it as hard as possible doesn't hurt. I'm thinking disabling right click will be as far as i go at this point. Thank you though.

Comment: I would really recommend against disabling right click. It's rarely a good idea to change the browser behavior since that can lead to other issues and can be super annoying for your users.

Comment: Ah, gotchea. I will look more into it, thank you.

Comment: Big reason being that the context menu does more than just save images or display the source. Example: I use Enpass as password manager. Enpass is in the context menu so I would need to open it separately and copy/paste the credentials instead of just auto fill from the context menu. It also doesn't really help you since anyone can simply do a screen shot of the page, go into the browsers dev tools to see the links or even just use the image in their browsers cache (which contains all the assets from all the pages you've visited).

Comment: Good point, appreciate the input.